# Unselect / exclude dynamic values for criteria in autofilter

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of data in a sheet called "raw" which consist of different animals. In the main sheet, I have a named range "rngAnimals" (Dynamic - User entry values) where I can list down values that I would like to exclude in autofilter and show the remaining data.

An example data:

```
| Animal   |
|----------|
| Dog      |
| Cat      |
| Bird     |
| Elephant |
| Horse    |
| Dog      |
| Dog      |
| Cat      |
| Bird     |
| Elephant |
| Horse    |
| Dog      |
```

In my named range "rngAnimals" , I specified values to exclude in the autofilter:

```
| Dog      |
| Cat      |
```

I have a working code, however, it does the opposite (shows values I have specified).

```
Sub UnselectCritera()


Dim vCrit As Variant
Dim inputSheet As Worksheet
Dim mainSheet As Worksheet

Dim rngCrit As Range
Dim rngOrders As Range

Set inputSheet = Worksheets("raw")
Set mainSheet = Worksheets("Main")

Set rngOrders = inputSheet.Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion
Set rngCrit = mainSheet.Range("rngAnimals")



vCrit = rngCrit.Value
rngOrders.AutoFilter _
Field:=1, _
Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(vCrit), _
Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

I have tried to change the "=" to something "<>", however it gives me an error:

```
rngOrders.AutoFilter _
Field:=1, _
Criteria1:="<>" & Application.Transpose(vCrit), _
Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Is there an alternative way so I will be able to exclude values I listed in showing when doing the autofilter?

Comment: Create an array with all unique values in `Animal` (using a **Dictionary**), then remove the 2 values in `rngAnimals`, and then filter according to that array

Comment: If you have more than 1 value set in `rngAnimals`, you will have to specify each item in that range as a separate criteria. i.e. **`rngOrders.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>Dog", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>Cat"`**

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestion. How do I do it with a dynamic range? As the list may grow in rngAnimals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my suggestion in the comments above, try the code below, explanations inside the code's comments:

***Modified Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub UnselectCritera()

Dim inputSheet As Worksheet
Dim mainSheet As Worksheet
Dim rngCrit As Range
Dim rngOrders As Range

' Dictionary variables
Dim Dict As Object, Key As Variant
Dim AnimalArr() As String, ArrIndex As Long, LastRow As Long, i As Long

Set inputSheet = Worksheets("raw")
Set mainSheet = Worksheets("Main")

Set rngOrders = inputSheet.Range("$A$1").CurrentRegion
Set rngCrit = mainSheet.Range("rngAnimals")

' use a Dictionary ro save unique Order numbers
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With inputSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ArrIndex = 1

    ReDim AnimalArr(1 To 10000) ' redim to very large number >> will optimize later
    For i = 1 To LastRow
       If Not Dict.Exists(.Range("A" & i).Value2) Then  ' current animal not in Dictionary >> add it as key
            ' check also that Animal is not in the second list
            If IsError(Application.Match(.Range("A" & i).Value2, rngCrit, 0)) Then ' Match failed >> not in second list of animals
                Dict.Add .Range("A" & i).Value2, .Range("A" & i).Value ' add Order number / Customer / Status

                ' array of numbers
                AnimalArr(ArrIndex) = .Range("A" & i).Value2
                ArrIndex = ArrIndex + 1
            End If
       End If
    Next i

    ReDim Preserve AnimalArr(1 To ArrIndex - 1) ' resize array to populated size
End With

' Filter according to Animal array (excluding the animals in the second list)
rngOrders.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=AnimalArr, Operator:=xlFilterValues

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tested the code and it works as expected. Thanks for the suggestion on the first comment, and I was thinking about it a quite while since, I'm not quite familiar with dictionary.

Comment: @Sevpoint you're welcome. Using a **Dictionary** with arrays is a powerful and useful tool. Combine that with `Match` and you will enjoy VBA so much more.

Comment: @Shai Rado: You can simplify your code by removing `AnimalArr` and its handling - just use `Criteria1:Dict.keys` in the `AutoFilter`-statement